# Calculate & add column length_of_time from date column in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr, calculated-columns, posixlt

I am trying to create a new calculated field, `length_of_time`. I have a column final_date with dates:

```
2/10/2016  
4/4/2016  
5/8/2016  
10/1/2016
```

and I am trying to calculate a new field showing length of time between 10/23/2016 and final_date.

I tried using dplyr:

```
mutate(df, length_of_time = 10/23/2016 - final_date)
```

and received an error:

> "Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
>     can only subtract from "POSIXt" objects"

so then I tried to use:

```
df <- as.POSIXlt(df$final_date)
```

and again ran my original code, only to receive the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('POSIXlt', 'POSIXt')"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got your date formats a bit confused. (see code comments for explanation)

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(final_date = c("2/10/2016","4/4/2016"))

## you need to specify the format of your date columns as it is ambiguous
## I've guessed you're using day/month/year
df$final_date <- as.POSIXct(df$final_date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

## and you need to subtract the `final_date` (which is POSIXct) 
## from another POSIXct object
mutate(df, length_of_time = as.POSIXct("2016-10-23") - final_date)

final_date length_of_time
1 2016-10-02  20.95833 days
2 2016-04-04 201.95833 days
```

#### Further Reading

- [Berkeley - Dates and Times in R](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html)
- [Handling date-times in R](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/ColeBeck/datestimes.pdf)

To help understand the difference between `POSIXct` and `POSIXlt`, date formats, date calculations etc.